# PHP - measuring database time for a HTTP request

Tags: php, logging

I want to find how much time a PHP http request spends in Database. Rails logger prints out such information (how much time is spent on rendering, database and app). Example:

```
Completed in 0.01224 (81 reqs/sec) | DB: 0.00044 (3%) | 302 Found [http://localhost/posts]
```

Is there something similar for PHP too?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) and [memory_get_usage()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) to test the speed as well as the *memory used* (which is often more important with ORM's).

```
$time = microtime(TRUE);
$memory = memory_get_usage();

...code here...

print (microtime(TRUE)-$time). ' seconds and '. (memory_get_usage()-$memory). ' bytes';
```

However, database queries should be benchmarked at the database level. Use [MySQL Query Profiler](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html) for real benchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use microtime to get the time before the query then subtract it from the time when the query finishes.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Answer (score 1):

Check out the PHP function microtime() 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php
I *think* this is what you're looking for, though I'm not sure.

Comment: So to display it in seconds I think you could use:  
echo number_format(microtime(),2);

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PHP has frameworks (Rails is a framework written in Ruby, PHP is a language) that have built in logging of how much time is spent on things like that. Look at Symfony, Kohana, Zend Framework, CodeIgniter.

Comment: This was a whack in the head for me. Indeed! Php is a language and not a framework. Thanks for the whack :-)